# Using nano_usb_programmer with Sensinodes

Tags: c

I am trying to use some old devices called sensinodes . There are a couple of pieces of software needed for this, contiki, sdcc and the some nano_usb_programmer

I'm working from these instruction and I can't seem to make the nano_usb_programmer on ubuntu 16.04 LTS as this pretty old now and things have moved on.

https://github.com/avian2/contiki

When making the nano element I get the error *Edited

```
    In file included from main.c:17:0:
opts.h:25:2: error: redefinition of typedef ‘mode_t’ with different type
 }mode_t;
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
                 from main.c:10:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:70:18: note: previous declaration of ‘mode_t’ was here
 typedef __mode_t mode_t;
                  ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:57:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘opts_parse’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (opts_parse(argc, argv) < 0)
      ^
main.c:77:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prog_scan’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    prog_scan();
    ^
main.c:178:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘hexfile_out’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       hexfile_out(line_data, 0x04, 0, ptr, 2);
       ^
main.c:220:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘hexfile_build_tables’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if((rval = hexfile_build_tables(opts.filename, page_buffer, page_table)) == -1)
               ^
main.c:231:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘hexfile_program’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    hexfile_program(page_buffer, page_table);
    ^
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

It is pointing to line 25 the following file, my c knowledge just isn't any where near good enough to fix this. Any help would be great.

```
/*
 * opts.h
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 21, 2009
 *      Author: martti
 */

#ifndef OPTS_H_
#define OPTS_H_

#include "cdi.h"

typedef enum
{
    USAGE,
    VERSION,
    SCAN,
    WRITE,
    WRITE_FAST,
    READ,
    WRITE_MAC,
    READ_MAC,
    LOCK,
    ERASE
}mode_t;

typedef struct opts_t
{
    int port;
    chip_t chip;
    mode_t mode;
    uint8_t write_mac[8];
    ramcode_t code_in_ram;
    char *filename;
}opts_t;

extern opts_t opts;

#endif /* OPTS_H_ */
```

Comment: Doesn't it also say something like `first defined at file:line`?

Comment: Updated the error output, it does also find it in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:70